# creating spark data frame based on condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 data frames:
`dataframe1` has 70000 rows like:

```
location_id, location, flag
1,Canada,active
2,Paris,active
3,London,active
4,Berlin,active
```

Second df `lookup` has modified ids for each location (This data frame is modified time to time), like:

```
id,location
1,Canada
10,Paris
4,Berlin
3,London
```

My problem is, I need to take new id as location_id from `lookup` and if `location_id` is different than `id` then, keep old id of corresponding location with flag name as inactive (to maintain historic data) and new id  with flag name as active for each location. So the output table in hive should look like:

```
location_id,location,flag
1,Canada,active
2,Paris,inactive
10,Paris,active
3,London,active
4,Berlin,active
```

I tried to join both frame first. Then on Joined DF, I am performing action, to save all records in hive.I tried the operations as:

```
val joinedFrame = dataframe1.join(lookup, "location")
val df_temp = joinedFrame.withColumn("flag1", when($"tag_id" === $"tag_number", "active").otherwise("inactive"))
var count = 1
df_temp.foreach(x => {
  val flag1 = x.getAs[String]("flag1").toString
  val flag = x.getAs[String]("flag").toString
  val location_id = x.getAs[String]("location_id").toString
  val location = x.getAs[String]("location").toString
  val id = x.getAs[String]("id").toString
  if ((count != 1)&&(flag1 != flag)){
    println("------not equal-------",flag1,"-------",flag,"---------",id,"---------",location,"--------",location_id)
    val df_main = sc.parallelize(Seq((location_id, location,flag1), (id, location, flag))).toDF("location_id", "location", "flag")
    df_main.show
    df_main.write.insertInto("location_coords")
  }
  count += 1
})
```

It prints the location values which has different ids, but while saving those values as dataframe, I am getting exception:

```
not equal------inactive------active---10---------Paris---------2    
17/09/29 03:43:29 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 45)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at $line83.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:75)
            at $line83.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:65)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    17/09/29 03:43:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 45, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
            at $line83.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:75)
            at $line83.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:65)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I do not think you can use ` sc.parallelize` when already looping over a dataframe with `foreach`.

Comment: @Shaido what should be the possible alternative then. Thanks.

Comment: Do you only want to save those rows where the id has changed?

Comment: @Shaido no, other rows are already in hive. I need to change only when id has changed. Then I need to save old id with inactive flag and new one as active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think the easiest method would be to use `join` on the ids instead. When doing an outer join the missing columns will end up having null, these rows are the ones that have been updated and you are interested in.

After that all that is left is to update the location column in case it is empty as well as the flag column, see my code below (note that I changed the column names somewhat):

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq((1,"Canada","active"),(2,"Paris","active"),(3,"London","active"),(4,"Berlin","active"))
  .toDF("id", "location", "flag")
val df2 = Seq((1,"Canada"),(10,"Paris"),(4,"Berlin"),(3,"London"))
  .toDF("id", "location_new") 

val df3 = df.join(df2, Seq("id"), "outer")
  .filter($"location".isNull or $"location_new".isNull)
  .withColumn("location", when($"location_new".isNull, $"location").otherwise($"location_new"))
  .withColumn("flag", when($"location" === $"location_new", "active").otherwise("inactive"))
  .drop("location_new")

> df3.show()
+---+--------+--------+
| id|location|    flag|
+---+--------+--------+
| 10|   Paris|  active|
|  2|   Paris|inactive|
+---+--------+--------+
```

After this you can use this new dataframe to update the hive table.